# Errors on Opencart website developed n local PC after being uploaded to live server

Tags: php, url, file-upload, opencart

I have developed an OC store on my local PC using XAMPP. I've uploaded the store to the server, and it's displaying well, BUT there are some irregularities. To cite an example, admin panel isn't functioning properly - I can sign in, but nothing is displayed then. I am almost sure the problem is in the urls, but as I have messed with the site once and had to reupload it, I more than welcome help from others. There are two sections of error messages - one in the header and one in the footer.

***Errors in the header:***

```
Warning: fopen(/home/davofvpt/public_html/storage/logs/openbay.log): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 22

Warning: fopen(/home/davofvpt/public_html/storage/logs/openbay.log): failed 
to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 22
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 39
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output 
started at /home/davofvpt/public_html/system/framework.php:42) in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/session.php on line 
25Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at /home/davofvpt/public_html/system/framework.php:42) in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php on line 
99Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by 
(output started at /home/davofvpt/public_html/system/framework.php:42) in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/catalog/controller/startup/startup.php on line 
157Warning: fopen(/home/davofvpt/public_html/storage/logs/openbay.log): 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 22
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 39
Warning: fopen(/home/davofvpt/public_html/storage/logs/error.log): failed to 
open stream: No such file or directory in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 22
```

***Errors in the footer:***

```
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 39Warning: 
fclose() 
expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 39Warning: 
fclose() 
expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/davofvpt/public_html/system/library/log.php on line 39
```

[Here is my config.php in the public folder](https://pastebin.com/QuwYAhBL)

[This is my config.php in the admin folder](https://pastebin.com/wL6N5ggA)

Comment: Whats is your OC version?

Comment: Its version is 3.0.2.

Comment: By the way, the site is davoodkhan.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have moved your "storage" folder from the main directory (such as system/storage) to other location.
please restore folder to moved location.

or install Opencart using auto installer.

If you are not expert in Opencart, then follow these steps.

---

1. Install new opencart(your required version).
2. Download or copy the config file from admin folder.
3. Upload your modified admin and catalog folder to server (using FTP).
4. Re-upload the downloaded config file to admin folder.

Now it works same as on localserver

Comment: Now, how do I optimize links? I mean the links are leading to my localhost directory, which, indeed, is not what I want.

Comment: @davoodkhan i didn't get what you mean actually. would you please elaborate it with an example

Comment: That's ok, I resolved it. Just needed to change some pages links. But Mohammed, can you please have a look at the website? I can't configure the social buttons on the product page - they were automatically added and there is nothing on them in the stylesheet. I tried deleting the AddThis portion in  product.twig file, but it didn't help. My goal is to either style the buttons or remove them all. Hope you can help.

Comment: it is not possible to style AddThis Social share icons but you can remove it from product page

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue by tracing the error message:

1. I created ($touch storage/logs/error.log) The file name is mentioned in the error message
2. I applied the permissions (chmod 777 storage/logs/error.log)
3. Did 1,2 for openbay.log
4. I noticed that the storage folder the owner _www which I changed to my user name (I dont think this step is required - just 1-3 should do the trick)

Note: I started with deleting the storage folder contents